# Struct inside of a struct in a struct

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

Wasn't sure how to title this question, but you can understand what is going on from the code:

```
typedef struct A {
     B* FirstB;
     //Some methods...
}

typdef struct B
{
     A* FirstA
     //Some methods...
}
```

I am trying to have a struct that has a struct in it, and the struct that it has in it has an instance pointer to the the struct it'self.  It's hard to explain but the code shows it well.

I'm not the greatest at C++, so can anyone point me in the right direction for doing something like this? Thanks.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: How can this be achieved..(with methods inside)

Comment: What is the problem you've encountered? What documenting material have you read so far? There must be a billion questions like this on SO. You're expected to read through some of them before re-asking.

Comment: Did you try it? Do some typedefs, build your top-level struct and construct it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are most likely having is that you can't declare each pointer until the other struct is declared, so there's no way to put one before the other. The solution is a *forward declaration*.

```
struct B;
struct A {
     B* FirstB;
     //Some methods...
}

struct B
{
     A* FirstA
     //Some methods...
}
```

The first line tells the compiler that there is a struct called `B`. It doesn't tell it what is in that struct, though. That way, you can declare a `B*` in `A` just fine. However, you will not be able to dereference that pointer until after `B` is declared, because the compiler doesn't know what members a `B` actually has until then. Thus, you will want to make sure you *declare* your methods in `A` and `B`, but *implement* them after both are declared.

Here's a complete example, with methods:

```
struct B;
struct A {
     B* FirstB;
     int foo();
};

struct B
{
     A* FirstA;
     int x;
};

A::foo() {
    return FirstB->x;
}

int main() {
    A outer;
    B inner;
    outer.FirstB = &B;
    inner.FirstA = &A;
    inner.x = 3;
    outer.foo(); //returns 3
}
```

Comment: @lanPudney This is good and works!  But how can this also be done with methods inside of it?